# How to get the list of java processes along with their PID(process id) that are running on UAT server under a specfic account?

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle

## Problem:

A jar file was failed to deploy on a UAT server.

## Reason:

Because when we are trying to rename it,it is showing 
"cannot rename the file it is been used by another user".

## step choosen in order to solve the problem

log on UAT server(xxx).

we need the list of java processes along with the PID on our UAT server
which is running under the account XXXAPPFUNC.

Please tell me how can I do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The database server we are using is microsoft sql server 2005.
The UAT server is windows server 2003 enterprise edition.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try the [`jps`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html) tool?

> ### DESCRIPTION
>
> The jps tool lists the instrumented
>   HotSpot Java Virtual Machines (JVMs)
>   on the target system. The tool is
>   limited to reporting information on
>   JVMs for which it has the access
>   permissions.
>
> ...
>
> The list of JVMs produced by the jps
>   command may be limited by the
>   permissions granted to the principal
>   running the command. The command will
>   only list the JVMs for which the
>   principle has access rights as
>   determined by operating system
>   specific access control mechanisms.
>
> ...
>
> ### OUTPUT FORMAT
>
> The output of the jps command follows the following pattern:
>
> ```
>  lvmid [ [ classname | JARfilename | "Unknown"] [ arg* ] [jvmarg* ] ]
> ```

For example, to list the instrumented JVMs on the local host:

```
$ jps
18027 Java2Demo.JAR
18032 jps
18005 jstat
```

Run it under the desired account.

Comment: I couldnt try this on the remote UAT server.
but i went through the web page and fund it very helpful.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) 
"Ever wondered which program has a particular file or directory open? Now you can find out. Process Explorer shows you information about which handles and DLLs processes have opened or loaded."
Doesn't just work for java processes.

Comment: Gary thank you very much .
I tried this it is giving information of all the processes and suits the requirement.
I will ask remote desktop assistance to install this software on the server and I will try it again thanks once again for your suggestion.